# Can printf() return differ from strlen()?

Tags: c, string

Just out of curiosity:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { BIG_NUMBER = 1024 };

int main(void)
{
    char mysterious_string[BIG_NUMBER];

    if (scanf("%1023s", mysterious_string) == 1) {

        if (printf("%s", mysterious_string) != strlen(mysterious_string)) {
            // Can this state occur?
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can the inner 'if' return true? Can I blindly trust both of these functions (`printf()` and `strlen()`) to return the right value?

Comment: Presumably it's safe to assume that the string will be valid?  (Not generally true for the above code, FWIW)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes, my mistake, edited the question \0

Comment: If the string includes a `\n` character, will it be modified on some platforms to include a `\r` in the output and, if so, will that additional character be accounted for in the return from `printf()`? If so, then no, they cannot be guaranteed to be equal.

Comment: @mah, surely this modification will happen at the OS level, in buffering the string into whatever device is displaying it, not at the program level?

Comment: @Ben yeah, that makes sense -- something in the vicinity of the serial (or other device) driver.

Comment: @mah I just tried something similar with `%%` in the string. The string here is *not* the "format string", but if it is, the lengths *are* different.

Comment: printf may be a subject of widechar-to-multibyte conversion, thus this `if` is not always true.

Answer (score 6):

It can absolutely be different.

If `printf` fails (for any number of reasons) then it will return a negative number which will not be the same as the value returned from `strlen`. In all other cases it will be the same.

*Note:* This is assuming the string is null terminated and that `scanf` works as expected.

Comment: If it's not null terminated, it's not a string.

Answer (score 4):

> Can the 'if' return true? Can I blindly trust both of these functions to return the right value?

Yes, it can return true (not equal).
Both functions can be trusted to return the "right" value with a compliant compiler and compliant code.  Yet the "right" value from those 2 functions may differ.

---

At least 3 cases:

1. `printf()` fails and returns -1  [@Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39235022/2410359), possible due to I/O error or other reasons.  This -1 will convert to `SIZE_MAX` as part of the `if (printf("%s", mysterious_string) != strlen(mysterious_string))` compare.
2. `strlen(mysterious_string) > INT_MAX`.  `printf()` returns an `int`, yet a string may be much longer.  `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, some unsigned type that may exceed the positive range of `int`.
3. The `"%s"` conversion exceeds environmental limits, then results may differ.  `scanf("%s", mysterious_string);` is not subject to that limit.

> The number of characters that can be produced by any single conversion shall be at least 4095.  C11dr §7.21.6.1 15

---

FWIW, printing on a windows machine printing with using the usual `\n` --> `\r\n` text mode translation still returned a 1 from `fprintf(text_file, "%s", "\n")` even though 2 characters were written to the file.